# jquery 1.3.2 with jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, igoogle

I am using http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/inettuts-with-cookies/ to show the widgets in user's dashboard as igoogle.

This plugin is not supporting with the jquery 1.3.2 and jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc2.min.js.

But it works fine with the older jquery version 1.2.6.

Does anyone faced this problem? How can i make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

change var notSortable = ''; to var notSortable = null;

Comment: i did that and the stop event of sortable() is not firing, to save the state of the widgets

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for a while with this one, finally got it to work in all browser versions with this combination

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js"></script>
```

My jquery ui is linked locally so you'll have to download your own copy.

Cheers